# How to remove 'Orders and Returns' from the footer?

Tags: magento

I've updated a fresh Magento 1.5.0.1 installation to Magento 1.6.0.0, and now I've got a link in the footer, "Orders and Returns", that I can't figure (yet) how to remove that.

I can't remove it from the core files, I've tried the XML method but doesn't seems to work (probably my fault).

At the moment I can't even localize where the link is generated, as simple tests (like putting random words where the output should appear) never works.

Anyone got any suggestion or a solution about?

Comment: I found the solution, but I've o wait 8h before I can post it, so I'll post it later :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here the solution.

Since I needed to keep it theme related, I duplicated the layout sales.xml from app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ to my theme layout folder (app/design/frontend/default/<name>/layout/) and commented out the `<action>` element from following snippet:

```
<default>
 <reference name="footer_links">
    <block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
    <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>return_link</blockName></action>
 </reference>
</default>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Matteo, if you use the one I suggested you can just put it in a local.xml layout file in the theme.  It ends up being less intrusive then as you don't need to edit the core layout file.

Answer (score 14):

You could try:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="return_link">
            <!-- Set the template file to an empty string to prevent output -->
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template></template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Or in 1.7+:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="removeLinkBlock">
                <blockName>return_link</blockName>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Or, as mentioned by Rumble:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="return_link" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

One caveat about using remove element is that it would prevent the usage of that block name anywhere in the layout as it is converted into a global xpath selector.

Comment: Hey Lee, thanks for your answer, I managed to fix my issue like I explianed in my answer :)

Comment: How can I disable this module completely?

Comment: Under Magento CE 1.7.1 the second solution did not work (nothing happened).  
The third one worked fine.

Comment: As there is, as of this post, no publicly available 1.7.1 release, it's  hard to verify your statement.  This question was specifically asked about 1.6.0.0 and the 1.7 branch wasn't even released when this was answered. (By released, I mean it wasn't out of alpha)

Answer (score 0):

There's a really simple way to remove this link. Add the following to your theme's `local.xml`

```
<default>
    <remove name="return_link"/>
</default>
```

There's a good introduction to using local.xml [here](http://classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout).

Comment: <remove> is a global tag that does not require a parent beyond the layout handle. (there is no reason to put it in a reference tag)