# How to remove Magento Orders and Returns Page

Tags: magento

Magento 1.6+ creates an Orders and Returns page (www.yourstore.com/sales/guest/form/) and places a link to it in the footer.

Removing the **link** in the footer is easy by adding layout update in local.xml ([see this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7193514/318090)).

But the page still exists, can be indexed by Google, and should be removed. How do I remove this default Magento page through code?

**EDIT:**
I want to clarify that I'm not looking for a redirect, rewrite, or 404 type answer. I'm looking for a way to literally remove or override whatever functionality is creating this page in the first place so it never gets created. My theory is that if the functionality exists to create it, then there should be a method to remove that functionality. I know there are other methods of hiding URLs via rewrites, etc. But it seems to me a preferred method is to not create unwanted pages and then hide them later. I would think Magento has some way of not producing pages it produces. Similar to how local.xml can remove blocks of unwanted code. Is there a similar method for preventing unwanted pages from being created in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use a URL rewrite to reroute the request to Magento's 404 page.  In your .htaccess file, add the following two lines after `RewriteEngine on` and before the other rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sales/guest/form
RewriteRule .* errors/404.php
```

If you need to remove this functionality from only a single site, you can wrap it up in Apache's `<If>` syntax like so:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sales/guest/form
    RewriteRule .* errors/404.php
</If>
```

If you prefer to do it with PHP code, other alternatives include overriding the Mage_Sales_GuestController class to return a redirect to the 404 page.  Or you could manipulate the routers to remove the URL from the routing table before routing occurs.  Both of these are a lot more complex and involved than the .htaccess solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I can rewrite or redirect it, but I'm looking for how to remove the page through Magento. Any help on how to do your other suggestions?

Comment: In the end, this was the simplest way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the local.xml method to replace the contents of the /sales/guest/form/ page with something else.  For example, you could put this handle in there...

```
<sales_guest_form>
  <reference name="content"> 
    <!-- Remove the main content of the page, which is the form -->
    <remove name="guest.form" />
    <!-- Optionally you can add in your own block or set of blocks. Not sure I would though -->
    <block type="yourmodlulealias/some_class" template="whatever/template.phtml" /> 
  </reference>
</sales_guest_form>
```

That will just remove the entire guest form, and replace it with a block of your own choosing.  Heck, you don't even have to add in your own block.

Another idea is to create an observer that listens for the controller_action_predispatch_sales_guest_form event, and just redirect whenever it is fired off.  This event is fired before the main processing for this page happens.  So the config.xml would probably have something similar to this...

```
        <controller_action_predispatch_sales_guest_form>
            <observers>
                <seo_redirect>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodulealias/observer</class>
                    <method>redirectRequest</method>
                </seo_redirect>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_sales_guest_form>
```

and then your observer class would look something similar to this...

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer {
  public function redirectRequest($observer){
    header("Location: " . Mage::getUrl() . 'someplace-else');
  }
}
```

If you don't like the idea of redirecting, you could go crazy and exit :)

**Edit:**
If you are dead set on making it look like that page doesn't exist, then maybe you can just return a 404 status. When a web server gets a request for a document that doesn't exist on the server it typically returns a 404.  In other words, a 404 means that the doc doesn't exist.  To do this you could use the observer idea from above and simply replace the redirect above with:

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer {
  public function redirectRequest($observer){
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
    exit;
  }
}
```

When you hit the page in your browser it will be totally blank, and the http header will say it is a 404 not found.  Another similar approach would be to make it so that Magento's default 404 page displays.  I haven't done this before, but I imagine that you would first need to override the controller (app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/GuestController) (look up how to override controllers if you aren't familiar, it is different from overriding models and blocks).  You would simply override the formAction() function in that class.  It would probably be something like this:

```
public function formAction()
{
  $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
  $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Along with this change you'll want to update the layout handle in your local.xml file to look like the  handle (which is in the cms.xml layout file).  So it would look something like this.

```
<sales_guest_form> 
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="default_no_route" template="cms/default/no-route.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</sales_guest_form>
```

Again, I haven't tested this last approach but it should work just fine.  Hitting http://yousite.com/sales/guest/form will bring you to the same Magento 404 page as if you went to some other non-existent url such as http://yoursite.com/some-non-existent-url.

Comment: Hi Shaune, thanks. It sounds like this doesn't remove the page either... the first suggestion just blanks it out, and the other redirects it. I'm still surprised there's no way to REMOVE a page Magento creates by default. This would be useful also for people who do not want the default contact page: /contacts/

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your desired outcome is.  When you say you want it to be removed, what *exactly* do you mean?  Do you want a custom 404 to be displayed when someone hits that url?  Or something else?  If it is google and other search engine bots that you are worried about you can easily tell them to stay away from specific webpages in your robots.txt. I think Jim and I have lined out pretty good ways of removing a magento page, so if you aren't satisfied please clarify your goals a little better.

Comment: There's a page at that URL, created by Magento code. How do I remove that page via Magento ways (code or whatever, not redirects or rewrites)? I understand I can do rewrites, robots.txt, etc. for SEO. That's not my question. That's like creating something then hiding it. How do we tell Magento not to create the page in the first place? For example, local.xml has  unSetChild methods of removing unwanted blocks. I've seen a small extension created to remove links that Magento creates but doesn't otherwise provide ways of removing. Looking for the same type of thing but for these pages.

Comment: Well I sort of understand what you are saying.  Sounds like you want a 404 to be returned.  I updated my answer to include two ways of doing it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Shaune, I appreciate you putting so much effort into this answer! But that still isn't my point. I don't want it LOOK like it doesn't exist via 404's or whatever. I don't want it to exist. Can't this returns page functionality be removed? Whatever functionality is creating it - remove or override it. That seems to be the way it "should" be done if it's unwanted, although at this point, yes, doing a quick .htaccess rewrite seems to be the quick fix. But it seems to me Magento should have a method of not producing unwanted pages in the first place. Maybe it doesn't exist, & if so, fine.

Comment: I started trying this, but it was getting too complicated (for me). But I do think this method is a solid way to go and ideally could be turned into an extension to "no-route" the returns page. But it was a bit beyond my skills, and so in the end, I did Jim's htaccess code.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as another answer because it's too long for a comment...

Anything that doesn't exist as a file (e.g. js/css. etc) the .htaccess rewrites will redirect though Magento's request handling process (starting at index.php).  So any URL like sales/guest/form will hit the Magento request handler regardless of whether it's defined by Magento or not.  At that point, if it matches a Magento controller action or can be routed to a Magento controller, Magento generates the appropriate page.  If the URL can't be resolved to a controller action, Magento generates a 404 page.

Hence any solution that responds with a 404 result, and does not allow the controller action to run is functionally the same as "removing" the page.

Comment: Using .htaccess is less desirable, since it's a multi-domain site, so I'd need to maintain it in 4 or more .htacess files, as opposed to one location if there's a way to tell Magento to remove the guest form page functionality.

Comment: There's nothing site specific in Magento's default .htaccess file, so there's no need to maintain a separate one for each domain.  If you wish to remove the page from a single store, I've enhanced my .htaccess example above showing how you could do that and maintain a single .htaccess file.  If your .htaccess file has become store specific by adding MAGE_RUN_CODEs for multi-store operations then you could use SetEnvIf either in your .htaccess or vhost definitions as described here (http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/setting-up-magento-with-multiple-websites-or-stores)